# Split one row into multiple rows in SQL with amounts divided equally

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that contains ID, an amount column and a count column. For each row I would like to split them into multiple rows, based on the count column. I would then like the amount column to be split evenly between these rows, and create a new id based on the original id and the row count.
This is how the table looks like:

```
ID      Amount   Count
1001    8        2
1002    15       3
```

And this is the desired output

```
ID      Amount
1001-1  4
1001-2  4
1002-1  5
1002-2  5
1002-3  5
```

Whats the best approach for this?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (`MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc. . .) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE.  This looks something like:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, amount / cnt as amount, cnt, 1 as lev 
      from t
      union all
      select id, amount, cnt, lev + 1
      from t
      where lev < cnt
     )
select id || '-' || lev, amount
from cte;
```

Note that this uses standard syntax; the exact syntax might vary depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Redshift does not support recursive queries.

Here is another option using a temporary table of numbers.

```
create temp table tmp(n int);
insert into tmp(n) values (1), (2), (3), (4), ...; -- expand as needed

select concat(t.id, '-', p.n) id, t.amount/t.count amount
from mytable t
inner join tmp p on p.n <= t.count
order by t.id, p.n
```